# orderby not working on custom query in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site and I need my custom query.I have managed to execute a query that look like

```
"SELECT wp_posts.*,a.meta_value as meta FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date"
```

This query executes fine I run this query in three places within a page

Now the problem is that I need to override the order by in one of the queries and need to do it by the value in the postmeta and query_posts does not seem to working
I tried

```
$args = array(
            'orderby' => 'meta',
            'order' => 'DESC'
);

query_posts($args);
```

But this is not overriding the query

if i try any field from wp_posts it seems to work

Any help?
Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Try:

'orderby' => 'meta_value',

Comment: I just did some searching. Check out this question. Seems similar to your. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10941/how-do-you-use-orderby-with-meta-query-in-wordpress-3-1

Comment: thanks worked!!!! i did do some searching i guess i missed it...been stuck for 4 hours now